# Auto insert %%time in beginning of all Jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to automatically insert the statement `%%time` in beginning of every Jupyter cell.

How can I do that?

Comment: My answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536092/import-py-flie-into-jupyter-notebook-line-by-line/53546796#53546796  to the other question is a good starter for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**execute_time**](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/execute_time) Jupyter Notebook extension to view the time taken in execution for every cell. Read the instructions [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).

[image]